# FormsAuthentication.Signout Issue - Different than any solved cookie issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, webforms

I have been struggling with this problem for a couple days and no answer on Stack will help. I am attempting to use FormsAuthentication.SignOut() and any other means to logout and it is still allowing the user into the site if the path is entered in the URL.

Here is some of the login code for reference:

```
if (adAuth.IsAuthenticated(txtDomain.Value, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
        {
            string groups = "Member"; //adAuth.GetGroups();

            //Create the ticket, and add the groups.
            bool isCookiePersistent = chkPersist.Checked;
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                      txtUsername.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), isCookiePersistent, groups); //"Member|" + groups);

            //Encrypt the ticket.
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

            //Create a cookie, and then add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
            HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

            if (isCookiePersistent)
                authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;

            //Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
            Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

            //You can redirect now.
            var redirectUrl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtUsername.Text, false);

            Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            errorLabel.Text = "Authentication did not succeed. Check user name and password.";
        }
```

Here are a few of the solutions I've tried to use to logout:

```
 Response.Cookies["adAuthCookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Response.Cookies.Clear();

        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Abandon();

        HttpContext.User =
new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);

        return Redirect("~/Create/Index");
```

And here is what I have in my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Create/Index" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="10" path="/"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

This is what I have in Global.asax:

```
oid Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            string encTicket = authCookie.Value;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(encTicket))
            {
                var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(encTicket);
                var id = new UserIdentity(ticket);
                var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(id.Name);
                var principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, userRoles);

                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've also tested that it doesn't matter if the cookie is persistent or not persistent.

Additionally, it may be important to note that the login page is an aspx web form, but the rest of the project is built using MVC.

This is not a duplicate because no current cookie solution is working. Does any know what could be going on. I must be missing something. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I have an [Authorize] attribute above the Index() ActionResult in my home controller. I noticed that if I double click logout, it will log the user out fully. Is there a quick fix I could use for now to register every click on the logout button as a double click?

Comment: Do you have `[Authorize]` attribute in top of controller actions.

Comment: I have added [Authorize] and it still let me in.

Comment: I take it you're not using a membership provider?

Comment: No, that would simplify things, but I am not able to.